# Windows / Python: Keyboard shortcut to perform a typed sequence

Tags: python, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

new to Python so there may be anothe rlanguage to do this in. Is there a way where I can type (for example `Ctrl + Shft + P` or `Alt + Shft + F8`that will then perform a key sequence - i.e. `this is to be input \tab now` and this will work at any point regardless of what I have open ect.

Comment: I suggest you look at C language as there are libraries that can do exactly that.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, do you know if you can do it in C++? Or what librarys in C would be best?

Comment: Not a pain, the only reason I know of it is due to a friend of mine, I do not know what libraries he used but it allowed him to create shortcuts that can be used when the script was running, i'll find out from him.